# How do lines of \framebox'es line up?

Tags: diagrams, framed

I want to stack boxes. The frame lines of the boxes should be exactly on top of each other.

### The original question

However, when I define two boxes, so that one starts where the other ends (spatially speaking), the lines do not overlap and I get a fat line, because of two thin lines next to each other. I have to move one box a little bit, so that it works the way I want it. See the MWE below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, titlepage]{article}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
\begin{picture}(6.6, 3.1)

\put(0.2,1.4){\framebox(2.4, 1){\shortstack{my bottom \\ is fat}}}
\put(0.2,0.7){\framebox(2.4, 0.7){}}

\end{picture}

\begin{picture}(6.6, 3.1)

\put(0.2,1.41){\framebox(2.4, 1){\shortstack{my bottom \\ is not fat}}}
\put(0.2,0.7){\framebox(2.4, 0.7){}}

\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But this "solution" is horrible, because if the line thickness is changed, it falls apart. Is there a way to say that the middle of the line should be the exactly on the edge of the box?

### Wait, there's more

So that M in MWE stands for minimal, right? So why bother including all those parameters for the document class that *shouldn't* matter here anyway. So in comparison to the first one this second MWE, the truly MWE, has no optional parameters for the document class:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
\begin{picture}(6.6, 3.1)

\put(0.2,1.4){\framebox(2.4, 1){\shortstack{my bottom \\ is fat}}}
\put(0.2,0.7){\framebox(2.4, 0.7){}}

\end{picture}

\begin{picture}(6.6, 3.1)

\put(0.2,1.41){\framebox(2.4, 1){\shortstack{my bottom \\ is not fat}}}
\put(0.2,0.7){\framebox(2.4, 0.7){}}

\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

To my surprise, this caused a bit of a swap in terms of fatness:

[image]

What's going on here? Under what conditions do the lines line up? What influences this? How can I make a prediction of what the picture will look like? When do I have to correct the position of the box and when not?

Comment: This is not the Monty Hall, but the [Shallow Hal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shallow_Hal) problem.

Comment: The frame is drawn “inside” the box. You should use `\makebox` and draw the borders with `\line`. I see no change in the two cases, what you seem to see is probably due to snapping of pixels to the grid at low resolution.

Comment: @egreg that sounds tedious, but looks like a valid workaround. Any idea on why it changes with different document class parameters?

Comment: As I said, it *doesn't* change. Apart from the size of characters, I get the same result in both cases: the top picture has a fatter mid line than the bottom one.

Comment: @egreg If they are drawn "inside", why does moving the top box up solve the problem then? Doesn't this solution suggest that they are drawn "outside of the box"?

Comment: Yes, I should have said *outside*. You may want to have a look at TikZ

Comment: You can tell which border belongs to which box if you color them differently: if you do so, you’ll see that each border is drawn “outside” its own box.

Answer (score 1):

If only two boxes need to be stacked, `tcolorbox` can be used. By default all tcolorboxes have upper and lower parts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{nobeforeafter}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{
   enhanced,
    notitle,
    colframe=black,
    colback=white,
    segmentation style={solid,line width=0.5mm},
    sharp corners,
    width=3cm,
    split=0.5,
    #1}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}
Upper part
\tcblower
Lower part
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}[height=4cm, valign=center]
Upper part
\tcblower
Lower part
\end{mybox}
\begin{mybox}[height=6cm, width=4cm, halign=center, valign lower=bottom]
Upper part
\tcblower
Lower part
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If more than two boxes are necessary, a possible solution could be a `TiKZ splited rectangle`, although in this case is more difficult to control empty parts height.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, draw, text width=2cm, align=center] (a) {Upper\nodepart{two}Lower};

\node[rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3, draw, text width=2cm, align=center, right = of a] (b) {Upper\nodepart{two}\rule{0pt}{2cm}\nodepart{three}};

\node[rectangle split, rectangle split parts=5, draw, text width=2cm, align=center, right=of b] (c) {Upper};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]